# Use method to style table in groovy

Tags: groovy, html-table, styling

I'm building a html email with groovy and I want to style my elements using a method. I want to use the method createTableCSS to set style to my table. But it doesn't work. The styling is coming outside the table tag.

```
String createTableCSS(String width, String border, String cellSpacing, String    background, String classes ){
 return "'width':'"+width+"'"
}

def responseDoc = job.addDocument("ECommerce_test.html"){out ->
  def xmlWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out)
  MarkupBuilder html = new MarkupBuilder(xmlWriter)
    html.doubleQuotes = true
    html.expandEmptyElements = true
    html.omitEmptyAttributes = false
    html.omitNullAttributes = false
    html.escapeAttributes = false
    html.html(lang:'en') {
        head {
            title('E-Commerce email')
            base('target':'_blank')
            meta('http-equiv' : 'Content-Type', 'content' : 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1')  
            meta('name':'viewport', 'content':'width=320')

         style(type:"text/css", '''  
         ''')

        }    
        body('style':'padding:0; margin:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; width:100%;','bgcolor':'#F2F2F2') { 
          div(){
            table(){ //Container table
              tr(){
                td('width':'20','class':'nomob'){ 
                } 
                td('align':'center'){ 

                  table(createTableCSS("640", "", "", "", "")){ 
                  }

                } 
                td(){ 
                } 
              }
            } 
          } 
        } //End <body>
     } //End <html>
  }
```

The result looks like this

```
<table>'width':'640'</table>
```

and it should look like this

```
<table width:"640"></table>
```

I can do this without a method, but would really like to know how to use a method in this type of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in here is, that using this method results in a string given as parameter into the table closure. What you need to make this work is a method returning a map. You can solve this by replacing your method with this one:

```
def createTableCSS(String width, String border, String cellSpacing, String    background, String classes) {
    return [width: width]
}
```